# putting javascript slide show in orchard cms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, slider, orchardcms

I want to put a simple slider on orchard. I have write the code and It is working on my computer. but when I add it to orchard CMS it doesn't work. can any one help me please. the asp version is 4.5 and iis 7.5 windows server 2008. here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var slideimages = new Array() // create new array to preload images
var slidenum=2
slideimages[0] = new Image() // create new instance of image object
slideimages[0].src = "emkanat1.JPG" // set image object src property to an image's src, preloading that image in the process
slideimages[1] = new Image()
slideimages[1].src = "emkanat2.JPG"
slideimages[2] = new Image()
slideimages[2].src = "emkanat3.JPG"


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display: block; width:940px; height:356px;">
<img src="emkanat1.JPG" id="slide" width="940px" height="356px" />
<div >
<img style="position:absolute; margin-top: 150px; margin-left: 10px;" src=left.jpg onclick="prev()"/>
<img style="position:absolute; margin-top: 150px; margin-left: 890px;" src=right.jpg onclick="next()"/>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

//variable that will increment through the images
var step=0

function slideit(){
 //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
 if (!document.images)
  return
 document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
 if (step<slidenum)
  step++
 else
  step=0
 //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
 setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}

function next(){
 if (!document.images)
  return

 if (step<slidenum)
  step++
 else
  step=0

  document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
}

function prev(){
 if (!document.images)
  return
  if (step>0)
  step--
 else
  step=slidenum

  document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
}



slideit()

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are your `;`? What doesn't work? Any console errors?

Comment: no, I add it in orchard CMS in tools part or content but it didn't slide pictures and I don't know what is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing "slideit()" as your first parameter to setTimeout, there are two ways this can go, you can have an implied eval where slideit() gets executed and then the result is passed to setTimeout, or you can have the string itself passed to setTimeout,  neither are what you want.  You should just pass the function as the first parameter of setTimeout.

change

```
setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
```

to

```
setTimeout(slideit,2500)
```

and you should be fine.